# Group by Hstore Key in PostgreSQL and ROR application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-postgresql, hstore

I'm working on a ROR application and i use Hstore with PostgreSQL data base and i'm asking if i can do group by an Hstore key on my table ??

I did this :

```
select state , count(*) from infractions group by details -> 'commune';`
```

but i get this error :

```
column "infractions.state" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

details is the Hstore column and her is an example of my details :

```
"adress"=>"", "commune"=>"14", "province"=>"6", "description"=>"Ce fichier est sous licence Creative Commons"
```

thanks

Comment: Check the error message: column "infractions.state" must appear in the GROUP BY clause. You must fix this first.

Comment: thanks but how I can fix this ??

Comment: "state" must be part of the group by, it's in your select without an aggregate function.

Comment: her is the solution 

    select state , count(*) from infractions group by state,details -> 'commune';

Comment: Can you add that as an answer so we can upvote it and show this has been answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People run into this occasionally when they move from MySQL.  MySQL allows columns to be omitted from the `GROUP BY` clause.  PostgreSQL does not.  Your actual issue is that you are missing the state column.  You have two options.  If you want to pull just one state you can put it in an aggregate like this:

```
select max(state) , count(*) from infractions group by details -> 'commune';
```

If you want to group by state too you can:

```
select state , count(*) from infractions group by state, details -> 'commune';
```